# Animating a circle using PIXI.js with Typescript

Tags: javascript, animation, typescript, pixi.js

I am using Typescript to animate a circle using PIXI.js. Currently, the circle is bouncing off of the bottom boundary then from the right boundary. I also need it to bounce from the top and left.

I am very new to this language and I'm having some difficulties understanding, well, most of it. I have tried nestling 'else' statements but I'm not sure if that's even suppose to be incorporated in this case.

'main.ts'

```
///<reference path="PIXI.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="setup.ts"/>

var drawing:PIXI.Graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
stage.addChild(drawing);

animate();
function animate() {
    renderer.render(stage);
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

var x:number = 0;
var y:number = 0;

var xspeed:number = 2;
var yspeed:number = 2;

// MY CODE

function draw(){

    // clear drawing
    drawing.clear();

    // draw circle
    drawing.beginFill(0x999999);
    drawing.drawCircle(x,y,100);

    // move circle down and to the right for the next frame
    x += xspeed;
    y += yspeed;

    // set boundary for circle to bounce from y
    if(y > 600){
        // bounce the circle
        yspeed *= -1;
        // affix to the bottom of the stage
        y = 600;
    }

    // set boundary for circle to bounce from x
    if(x > 800){
        xspeed *= -1;
        x = 800;
    }

}
```

HTML

```
    <script src="src/pixi.js"></script>
    <script src="src/setup.js"></script>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you've got so far is good. You just need to add checks for the zero boundaries:

```
// set boundaries for circle to bounce from y
if(y > 600){
    // bounce the circle
    yspeed *= -1;
    // affix to the bottom of the stage
    y = 600;
}
else if(y < 0) {
    // bounce the circle
    yspeed *= -1;
    // affix to the top of the stage
    y = 0;
}

// set boundaries for circle to bounce from x
if(x > 800){
    xspeed *= -1;
    x = 800;
}
else if(x < 0){
    xspeed *= -1;
    x = 0;
}
```

Another thing you might like to try is drawing the circle once, and setting its x and y properties instead of redrawing it every frame:

```
var drawing:PIXI.Graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
drawing.beginFill(0x999999);
drawing.drawCircle(0,0,100);
stage.addChild(drawing);


function draw(){

    // move circle
    drawing.x = x;
    drawing.y = y;

    // move circle down and to the right for the next frame
    x += xspeed;
    y += yspeed;
```

Comment: I was pretty close; I was setting the else-if to 10 instead of 0... But thank you so much for the help and for the other tip! That is something I'm going to incorporate.